# After accidentally deletion of /usr, pip does not find dependencies

Tags: python, debian, pip

Because of error in my shell script I have accidentally deleted the /usr directory, then restored if from early backup of this virtual machine, then reinstalled all the packages for it, now almost everything works fine, except that:

```
# pip install --no-install --download-cache="./" django-celery
Downloading/unpacking django-celery
  Using download cache from ./https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fd%2Fdjango-celery%2Fdjango-celery-3.0.17.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-celery
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bin/*.pyc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests/*.pyc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/*.pyc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'extra/*.pyc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'djcelery/*.pyc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/.build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*.pyc'
Downloading/unpacking pytz (from django-celery)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from django-celery) (from versions: 2009r, 2008b, 2009f, 2008c, 2007g, 2011g, 2005m, 2011e, 2007f, 2011k, 2007k, 2006j, 2008h, 2008i, 2011e, 2008a, 2009e, 2006g, 2011j, 2010l, 2005m, 2008i, 2005k, 2008g, 2007c, 2007i, 2009l, 2009r, 2006j, 2011k, 2007d, 2006p, 2009i, 2009u, 2007i, 2009f, 2010g, 2008h, 2009a, 2007g, 2011e, 2006p, 2012b, 2010k, 2005r, 2007f, 2009l, 2009p, 2008c, 2009j, 2008g, 2010g, 2010h, 2011h, 2010k, 2007c, 2007d, 2011d, 2009l, 2011c, 2008a, 2005m, 2007k, 2009n, 2011d, 2010o, 2013b, 2012h, 2010e, 2012c, 2012d, 2012f, 2011n, 2011b, 2011j, 2008c, 2012j, 2007k, 2009f, 2009d, 2010e, 2010b, 2013b, 2011d, 2009p, 2008h, 2005r, 2009i, 2009n, 2009a, 2010k, 2008g, 2006g, 2008b, 2012c, 2009i, 2007g, 2012c, 2010h, 2011n, 2012g, 2007d, 2008a, 2009u, 2012g, 2010o, 2006p, 2010b, 2009u, 2012d, 2011k, 2012f, 2009a, 2007f, 2011h, 2010l, 2009j, 2011g, 2009g, 2009g, 2005r, 2011c, 2012g, 2009g, 2012d, 2009j, 2010o, 2007c, 2010g, 2006g, 2009d, 2010h, 2005k, 2006j, 2010b, 2009n, 2011g, 2011c, 2012b, 2009e, 2009d, 2011j, 2007i, 2012j, 2010l, 2009r, 2012h, 2010e, 2009p, 2008i, 2012f, 2009e, 2012b, 2011h, 2005k, 2008b, 2011n, 2012j, 2013b, 2004b)
No distributions matching the version for pytz (from django-celery)
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

content of /root/.pip/pip.log - http://paste.kde.org/pbe71b739/

System - Debian squeeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `pip` bug. The `pip` team has [already closed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/974) this issue, so as workaround you can manually install pytz with particular version before installing anything else:

```
pip install pytz==2013k
```

or more convenient:

```
pip install --pre pytz
```

According to the issue discussion, pip is confused about `pytz` versioning and latest `release` versions were wrongly interpreted as `prerelease`. With --pre option you can force install `prerelease` version which is actually `release`.

Then you'll be able to install other packages that are depending on pytz.